# Gulp restart on every change

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I have the following github repo which I use as a starting point for my angular/browserify apps (https://github.com/mcneela86/angular-gulp-browserify). When I am using the project I can run `gulp` and everything works fine, however, everytime I change the code I need to re-run `gulp` due to some error.

I have been trying to figure out the error, but as far as I can see it should be working, can anybody help?

Comment: Posting the error would greatly increase your odds of getting a helpful response.

Comment: try adding `watch = require('gulp-watch')`